# how to remove u from sqlite3 cursor.fetchall() in python

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
class class1:
def __init__(self):
    self.print1()
def print1(self):
    con = sqlite3.connect('mydb.sqlite')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select fname from tblsample1 order by fname")
    ar=cur.fetchall()
    print(ar)

class1()
```

gives an output as shown below

```
[(u'arun',), (u'kiran',), (u'kulku',), (u'sugu',)]
```

i need to remove u from the array and i need output as shown below

```
['arun', 'kiran', 'kulku', 'sugu']
```

Answer (score 24):

If you need that strings retrieved from your sqlite database be returned as UTF-8 instead of Unicode, set-up your connection accordingly using the text_factory propery:

```
import sqlite3
class class1:
def __init__(self):
    self.print1()
def print1(self):
    con = sqlite3.connect('mydb.sqlite')
    con.text_factory = str
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select fname from tblsample1 order by fname")
    ar=cur.fetchall()
    print(ar)

class1()
```

See this for the details:
http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.text_factory

That takes care of the "u" in front of your strings. You'll then have to convert your list of tuples to a list:

```
ar=[r[0] for r in cur.fetchall()]
```

Answer (score 10):

The `u` prefix indicates that the string is an [Unicode](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) string. If you're sure that the string is a basic ASCII string, you can transform the unicode string into a non-unicode one with a simple `str()`.

Example :

```
unicode_foo = u"foo"
print unicode_foo
>>> u"foo"

print str(unicode_foo)
>>> "foo"
```

In your case, with a list of tuples, you'll have to do such with a python list comprehension :

```
ar = [[str(item) for item in results] for results in cur.fetchall()]
```

Where `results` is the list of tuples returned by `fetchall`, and `item` are the members of the tuples.

Comment: please give me the explanation for `ar = [str(item[0]) for item in cur.fetchall()]
` __thank you__

Comment: @KIRAN : I edited my answer to transform all the items returned by the `fetchall` method.

Answer (score 2):

the u tells you that these are unicode strings. to print the list of tuples in the format you specified you could use:

```
>>> myformat="['%s']"%"', '".join([t[0] for t in ar])
>>> print myformat
['arun', 'kiran', 'kulku', 'sugu']
```

edit://
Example for KIRAN with u and , in the result set:

```
>>> ar=[(u'u',), (u'u',), (u',,,u,,u,',)]
>>> myformat="['%s']"%"', '".join([t[0] for t in ar])
>>> print myformat
['u', 'u', ',,,u,,u,']
```

Comment: i think it is not a safe method.please suggest another one.`Thank you verymuch`

Comment: I don't see how this would cause a problem. show me an example where it fails please.

Comment: I'm assuming that KIRAN's concern is that by manually constructing a [repr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr) of the list you'll possibly create a different list, or a broken list.

Comment: I was assuming by "i need output as shown below" he is interested only in the console output format which looks similar to a list repr, not in creating a new list. your answer seems to satisfy both cases, I'll vote for you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I just add this line and it works

```
conn.text_factory = str
```