# Select Postgresql Schemas in Python, output not as expected

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to get all Schemas with "master" keyword in it. I got it, but my output looks like tuple parts and I would like only to get strings.

I did this:

```
def get_all_schemas():
    tmp_arr = []
    for name in db.engine.execute("""select schema_name from information_schema.schemata
                                    where schema_name like 'master%%' order by 1"""):
        tmp_arr.append({"name": name})
        print(tmp_arr)
    return tmp_arr
```

My output looks like:

> [{'name': (u'master',)}, {'name': (u'master_old',)}, {'name':
>   (u'master_old1',)}]

and I would like:

> [{'name': 'master'}, {'name': 'master_old'}, {'name': 'master_old1'}]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modification:**

```
tmp_arr.append({"name": str(name[0])})
```

**Sample:**

```
a=(u'master',)    
str(a[0])
'master'
```

The output of your `query` is `tuple with Unicode string` so you can get first element using `[0]` and can convert it into acsii strings using `str()`  for more on converting string see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855645/how-to-turn-unicode-strings-into-regular-strings) and this [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547658/how-to-remove-u-from-sqlite3-cursor-fetchall-in-python)